# Quicksort input text C++

Tags: c++

here is my Quicksort code

```
int n = 7;
int A[7] = {2,4,3,2,6,7,5};       

void QuickSort (int A[],int left, int right)
{
    int x = A[(left + right)/2];
    int i = left,
        j = right;
    do
    {
        while (A[i]<x)
        i++;
        while (A[j]>x)
        j--;
        if (i<=j)
        {
            Swap(A[i],A[j]);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    while (i<j);
    if (left < j)
    QuickSort(A,left,j);
    if (i<right)
    QuickSort(A,i,right);
}
```

How can I use quicksort for .txt?
I am a newbie so I just need a simple way to read this file.

Comment: Open the text file, load it into memory, sort it, write it back. That's the most basic approach.

Comment: I do not really understand this step: if (left < j) and (i < right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to learn File I/O with C++.

Basically you include `<fstream>` and create instances of `fstream` (for I/O), `ifstream` (for input only) or `ofstream` (for output only). Then you open a file and use the object as you usually do with `cin`/`cout`.

[Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%2B%2B+File+IO)'s a Google search. The first page contains a lot of useful tutorials. Follow one of them and you'll be on your way soon.

Comment: thanks for your help. I finally found the way to solve this situation